# can't 'convert' typescript definition in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to rewrite [this Apollo typescript repository](https://github.com/apollographql/ac3-state-management-examples/tree/master/apollo-local-state) to javascript.
I try to learn typescript but there is one thing called 'type casting' or 'type assertion' which makes me confuse.

let me explain it with code:

`//cache.tsx`

```
import { InMemoryCache, ReactiveVar, makeVar } from "@apollo/client";
import { Todos } from "./models/Todos";
import { VisibilityFilter, VisibilityFilters } from "./models/VisibilityFilter";

export const cache...{
...
...
}


export const todosVar: ReactiveVar<Todos> = makeVar<Todos>( //how i can 'convert' this type caster value to vanilla js?
  todosInitialValue 
);

export const visibilityFilterVar = makeVar<VisibilityFilter>(  //how i can 'convert' this type caster value to vanilla js?
  VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ALL
)
```

other 2 files which are used by this cache.tsx are:

`//todos.tsx`

```
export interface Todo {
  text: string;
  completed: boolean;
  id: number
}

export type Todos = Todo[];
```

and

`VisibilityFilter.tsx`

```
export type VisibilityFilter = {
  id: string;
  displayName: string;
}

export const VisibilityFilters: { [filter: string]: VisibilityFilter } = {
  SHOW_ALL: {
    id: "show_all",
    displayName: "All"
  },
  SHOW_COMPLETED: {
    id: "show_completed",
    displayName: "Completed"
  },
  SHOW_ACTIVE: {
    id: "show_active",
    displayName: "Active"
  }
}
```

How can I avoid typescript type checking in this situation and more important, how can I use ReactiveVar and makeVar imports properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just remove the generic like this:**

From:

```
makeVar<Todos>(
```

To:

```
makeVar(
```

Change this:

```
export const todosVar: ReactiveVar<Todos> = makeVar<Todos>( //how i can 'convert' this type caster value to vanilla js?
  todosInitialValue 
);

export const visibilityFilterVar = makeVar<VisibilityFilter>(  //how i can 'convert' this type caster value to vanilla js?
  VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ALL
)
```

To this:

```js
export const todosVar = makeVar(todosInitialValue);
export const visibilityFilterVar = makeVar(VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ALL);
```

How to avoid typescript checking - replace your extensions from .ts and .tsx to .js and .jsx respectively.